# How to return data from a dialog box to the main activity in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am making a list app using rooms for database. I created a dialog box to add things to the list. How do I return the data from a dialog to add items to the main activity.

AddListDialog.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_url)

    tvAddToLib.setOnClickListener{
        val content  = etContent.text.toString()
       
        if (content.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Enter Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@setOnClickListener
         }

        val item = UrlList(addTime, content, readTime = null)
        addDialogListener.onAddButtonClicked(item)
        dismiss()
    }

    tvCancel.setOnClickListener {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Main Activity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val dao = ListDao
    val repository = UrlRepository(dao)
    val factory = ListViewModelFactory(repository)
    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)

    val adapter = ListAdapter(listOf(), viewModel)

    rvListenItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvListenItems.adapter = adapter

    viewModel.getList().observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.items = it
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

    fabAdd.setOnClickListener {
        AddUrlDialog(this, object : AddDialogListener{
            override suspend fun onAddButtonClicked(item: List) {
                 viewModel.upsert(item)
            }
        }).show()

    }
```

Adddialoglistener.kt

```
import com.example.listen.data.db.entities.List

interface AddDialogListener {

    suspend fun onAddButtonClicked(item : List)
}
```

Comment: AddDialogListener have done. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use a new .xml layout and ContentView(layoutid) it on your main activity as a dialog ? lets make one dialog with list now.

first make your .xml layout that will contain a list, we will use as a dialog to return any actions from it in the same kotlain main class.

see pictures ^_^ i hope it will work, good luck.

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4viV.png)

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui2mr.png)

[step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nkQe.png)

[step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlYIN.png)

[step5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l97FC.png)

[step6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuXpv.png)

[step7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC0qr.png)

[step8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7fsz.png)

i have made a horizontal list of buttons instead, i thought it would be cool !, but you can put anything in your .xml layout then as i illustrated .show()
it as dialog setting it in the contentView(layoutID) of the dialog you have initiated in anywhere ^_^, good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).